# Find groups of increasing numbers (with varying deltas) within list

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a list containing 'groups' of increasing numbers with varying deltas. Here's an example:

```
l = [0, 1, 5, 8, 10, 20, 30, 40, 45, 48, 77, 100, 200, 300, 400]
```

I would like to get back:

```
[[0], [1], [5], [8], [10, 20, 30, 40], [45], [48], [77], [100, 200, 300, 400]]
```

Explanation: The 0, 1, 5, 8 don't follow a fixed delta (+1, +4, +3), while [10, 20, 30, 40] all have a fixed +10 delta.

---

I see how this could be done using for loops and `curr_group`, `curr_delta`, etc. variables, but I would like to avoid this.

Using pandas, I was able get this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [0, 1, 5, 8, 10, 20, 30, 40, 45, 48, 77, 100, 200, 300, 400]})
df['shift_diff'] = (df.diff() != df.diff().shift(-1)).astype('int')
df['group'] = df.shift_diff.cumsum()
print list(df.groupby('group').col.apply(list))
```

which outputs

```
[[0], [1], [5], [8], [10, 20, 30], [40], [45], [48], [77], [100, 200, 300], [400]]
```

Pretty close, but all groups with length > 1 (the `[10, 20, 30]` and `[100, 200, 300]`) are missing their last element.

A short and elegant solution would be appreciated! Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want ?

```
df['group'] = (~((df-df.shift()).diff().eq(0)|(df-df.shift(-1)).diff().eq(0))).cumsum()
print(list(df.groupby('group').col.apply(list)))
[[0], [1], [5], [8], [10, 20, 30, 40], [45], [48], [77], [100, 200, 300, 400]]
```

Comment: That's... beautiful. Thank you very very much! I had a feeling there was a bool logic trick somewhere in there. Kudos! May I ask how did you come up with this solution? Is this a common diff/shift trick? Thanks!

Comment: @GregSadetsky   it is diff of diff , so we losing two cells'  information for each group , `shift` done we lose bottom two , `shift` up we loss top two , then we using the logic `or` we get all :-)

Comment: I think I got it -- the `(df-df.shift()).diff()` computes the delta of the delta of increasing values, while the second `(df-df.shift(-1)).diff()` does the same in the other direction. Any time the delta of the delta is 0, numbers are increasing regularly (which `.eq(0)` checks). A logic not and cumsum() complete the picture. Brilliant! :-) Thanks again

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need `pandas`, though it is maybe faster. I don't know.

I put the explanation in the code as comments:

```
array = [1, 4, 5, 10, 20, 30, 40, 15, 17, 19, 2, 5, 3, 100, 200, 300, 400]

def f(array):
    if len(array) == 1: return [array] # Special case for singleton array
    if len(array) == 2: return [[array[0]], [array[1]]] # Special case for pair
    results = []
    index = 2
    while index < len(array): # This will look back by 2, so if the array is too small, apply special cases
        delta = array[index] - array[index - 1] # Difference between current and last element
        if delta == array[index - 1] - array[index - 2]: # If the three elements are all equal
            results.append(array[index - 2:index + 1]) # Append the group of the current three elements
            index += 1 # Go forward one
            while index < len(array) and delta == array[index] - array[index - 1]: # Keep adding until the list is exhausted or the next element is no longer part of this group
                results[-1].append(array[index]) # Add the current element
                index += 1
        else: # If the three elements don't have the same deltas
            results.append([array[index - 2]]) # Append the element and keep going
        index += 1
    return results

print(f(array))
```

You can try it online [here](https://tio.run/##dVPBjtMwED3HXzESB1qRRU27CFHRAxISQhzhFvngjSeNta4dbIe2X1/GdsK2JXtwFI9f3rz3xunPobNmc7kI58QZdlBXJTyW8KGEalXCmtaG1iOtKtY@0vpE9YTYRFBCJVjCrThjEltoF4lxuWWFakGjGfew20G1BYdhcAbqVOTwBn722CihoREeobUOvDJ7jcEaSJgZmvULTeapV5yXI2ddcT7L2wvlWOHQDzr4aJgTtZF4ovc1K46d0gi58Pmq4Za4fnXKw1FpDdraZ3gSDT3OMQxvgeSFDrNYIFywFvxBaF2C6Ht9Bn@lxLOikKiDoKZZburI4eF6S7sqeviq2hYdmgbhCcMR0UAzOCoEEEaCFj4AajxQgXhJyEi9@5/snn/No7HvWXvoHOLE5AlJdsgs/h6EJuIptPfkB41c3DFt89s7arMkzi8JlHj3zg492NxkUn7bLNKP39P9oM@/2Tito3ASrMF4/NpkUgZzjufSjG5/IPYgpKQLBoMJSiddWlGKNDc8dWLwAamvSwcGT//ijQBjafxmj/EquZBtUTmZjDqnmOqHis9ElcOR8iaMl@ldx0Bb1B5fn5C05m2ATvzBdOrFAXMSfmZc9f3k78c0eYx5PseM9pYiYreKxj9u5Gasd8qExfS3Ly@Xvw) and that also makes reading comments easier since it's wide enough to fit the comments

Answer (score 1):

Here is a python version that uses a lazy function to find the length of similar differences in a list.  Input a list returns a generator that will return the number of elements that share a difference, unless the difference is singular, in which case it returns 1.

You can use it to slice the list into chunks to create the new list.

```
from itertools import groupby

def diff_group_len(x):
    dx = (x2-x1 for x1,x2 in zip(x,x[1:]))
    dg = (len(tuple(g)) for _,g in groupby(dx))
    SKIP = False
    for group_size in dg:
        if SKIP:
            SKIP = False
            continue
        if group_size>1:
            SKIP = True
            yield group_size+1
        else:
            yield group_size
```

Once that is defined, we can use it to find the length of clumps in our list.  The lengths are used to slice the list up.

```
out = []
start = 0
for s in diff_group_len(l):
    out.append(l[start:start+s])
    start += s

out
# returns:
[[0],
 [1],
 [5],
 [8],
 [10, 20, 30, 40],
 [45, 48, 51],
 [77],
 [100, 200, 300, 400]]
```